# How can I use OR operator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use an or operator to get my function to return "true" if user inputs one of two different answers. With the code below, I keep getting "use of unresolved identifier check2" even though I've initialized check2.

```
func checkAnswer() {

let check = user.caseInsensitiveCompare(quizbrain.getAnswerText()) == .orderedSame
        
        if quizbrain.getAltText() != nil {
            let check2 = user2!.caseInsensitiveCompare(quizbrain.getAltText()!) == .orderedSame
        }
              else {
                  check2 = false
              }
        
        if check || check2 {
            resultLabel.text = "Correct, you answered " + "\"" + user + "\""
            print("correct")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know about *scope*. Code can only see a name if it is declared in the same "place". A "place" is (among other things) a matching set of curly braces. Code inside curly braces is *invisible* outside of those curly braces.

So if we indent properly, we can see the issue:

```
if quizbrain.getAltText() != nil {
    let check2 = // <<---- declaration
} else {
    check2 = false // ????
}
if check || check2 { // ???
```

As you can see, `check2` is declared (`let`) *inside* the first set of curly braces. And there it will stay! It cannot leak out of those curly braces. So the other two uses of the word `check2` cannot see that `let check2` and they do not know that any `check2` exists.

But if we move the declaration to a higher scope (and use `var`), all is well:

```
var check2 = false
if quizbrain.getAltText() != nil {
    check2 = // ...
}
if check || check2 {
```

The code inside the first curly braces *can* see *that* `check2` declaration, because it is further up the scope hierarchy; and so can later code at the same level.